# Using a binary on Ubuntu 16.04 built on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cross-compiling

Our CI Server runs on Ubuntu 14.04 while we just updated a part of our Production environment to Ubuntu. The problem: The binary built on Ubuntu 14.04 does not run on Ubuntu 16.04, while the binary with the same makefile built on my laptop with ubuntu 16.04 runs fine on the server.

The Binary is built with g++ 5.x on 14.04 (as well as on 16.04) and has basically mongocxx and poco as dependencies. The dependencies are installed with the same script on all machines.

but when I run the binary built on 14.04, I find none of the self installed dependencies (symbol not found)

what do I need to look for when compiling the dependencies? what are the differences (in the end both is ubuntu?)

Comment: Just install the appropriate run-time libraries and it will run. I am typing this on a system which was upgraded over many Ubuntu releases; the run-time libraries will coexist just fine.   Generally you can "port forward" (ie compile on 14.04 and run on 16.04) but not "backwards".